# How can I use PHP to seed a dynamic table in a form with a users previously submitted answers?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, html-table

It's a complicated title, I know. I think an example would best illustrate what I mean:

Let's say I'm asking the user for their favorite Rock albums: albumName and albumArtist. I have a table with two columns that starts out with only one row. When the user clicks a button, a javascript function adds another row with the appropriate input fields in the appropriate cells. Then all of this data is stored in a MySQL table. This all works fine.

When the user comes back, I'd like to re-render the table, inserting all of the user's submitted values. However, when I call the same JS function using PHP `<echo>` it renders above the form. How can I fix this?

Sample code below:

Javascript in head:

```
function addInputCell(newRow, cellNum, size, maxLength, fieldID, inputID, value)
{
  var newCell = newRow.insertCell(cellNum);
  var elem = document.createElement('input');
  elem.type = 'text';
  elem.size = size;
  elem.maxlength = maxLength;
  elem.name = fieldID + inputID;
  elem.value = value;
  newCell.appendChild(elem);
  alert(elem.value);
}

function add3CellRow(fieldID, size1, maxlength1, size2, maxlength2, value)
{
  var table = document.getElementById(fieldID);
  var lastRow = table.rows.length;

  if(lastRow <22){
    var newRow = table.insertRow(lastRow - 1);

    var cellLeft = newRow.insertCell(0);
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(lastRow - 1);
    cellLeft.appendChild(textNode);

    addInputCell(newRow, 1, size1, maxlength1, fieldID, 'Name[]', value);
    addInputCell(newRow, 2, size2, maxlength2, fieldID, 'Artist[]', value);
  }
  else
  {
    alert('You can only enter 20 values in this field');
  }
}
```

HTML in body:

```
<table width="450" border="0" id='album' cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">   
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td width="3"></td>
      <td width="90%" align="center"><b>Album Name</b></td>
      <td width="10%" align="center"><b>Album Artist</b></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tr>
    <td align="right">1</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="20" name="albumName[]" maxlength="20" value='<?php echo($onfile['albumName']);?>'/></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="20" name="albumArtist[]" maxlength="20" value='<?php echo($onfile['albumArtist']);?>'/> </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td align="right"><input type="button" value="Add Concern" onClick="add3CellRow('album',20,20,20,20 ,'');"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

PHP in body:

```
<?php 
  echo ("<script type='text/javascript'>");

  //Get the data in the rock table where userID matches
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rock WHERE userID = '$_SESSION[userID]'");

  while($onfile = mysql_fetch_array($result)) //Set the data into an array
  {
    echo ("add3CellRow('rock',20,20,20,20, '$onfileConcern[albumName]');");
  }
  echo ("</script>");
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. Created a PHP function that is called onLoad. Included below. Note the first entry is ignored as it is already displayed in the HTML section of the code

```
function displayData()
{
$ii = 0;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rock WHERE userID = '$_SESSION[userID]'"); //Get the data in the concern table where userID matches
while($onfile = mysql_fetch_array($result)) //Set the data into an array
{
    if($ii > 0)
    {
        echo ("add3CellRow('rock',20,20,20,20, '$onfile[albumName]','$onfile[albumArtist]');");
    }
    $ii += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure if this is the answer you are looking for, but if it is being stored in the database, just take the data from the database, echo it into the "value" attribute for the input tags, and the info should be there.

Example:

```
<input type='text' value='<?php echo $firstName ?> name='firstName' />
```

The $firstName would have the value of whatever the user previously had stored in the database.

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: That is exactly what I want, but I don't know how to do that for an unknown number of values, to be insert in rows that haven't been created yet. 

In the HTML section, I do exactly that for the first row however

Comment: Got it. Created a PHP function that is called onLoad. Included below. Note the first entry is ignored as it is already displayed in the HTML section above.

    function displayData()
    {
 $ii = 0;
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rock WHERE userID = '$_SESSION[userID]'"); //Get the data in the concern table where userID matches
 while($onfile = mysql_fetch_array($result)) //Set the data into an array
 {
  if($ii > 0)
  {
   echo ("add3CellRow('rock',20,20,20,20, '$onfileConcern[albumName]','$onfileConcern[albumArtist]');");
  }
  $ii += 1;
 }

Comment: Oh sorry for my absence.  Glad you got it though.

Comment: @Dimitri If this is a good answer to your question, use the checkmark! Let us know! Also, be sure to use ` around your code blocks in comments. They make the blocks more readable.

Comment: @cwallenpoole: I tried but being a new user I wasn't allowed to answer my own question for 8 hours, so I posted it as a comment. In another 24 hours I'll use the check mark. Thank you for your patience and advice for a new user!